# How should I write custom install and uninstall nsis for electron builder?

Tags: python, electron, nsis, electron-builder

## hello, I am building an electron app.

### I need to do 2 things while installing the app

##### 1.set custom installation path

here is the the code how I done the first step

```
!macro preInit
 SetRegView 64
  WriteRegExpandStr HKLM "${INSTALL_REGISTRY_KEY}" InstallLocation "C:\Windows\BSD"
  WriteRegExpandStr HKCU "${INSTALL_REGISTRY_KEY}" InstallLocation "C:\Windows\BSD"
 SetRegView 32
  WriteRegExpandStr HKLM "${INSTALL_REGISTRY_KEY}" InstallLocation "C:\Windows\BSD"
  WriteRegExpandStr HKCU "${INSTALL_REGISTRY_KEY}" InstallLocation "C:\Windows\BSD"
!macroend
```

And in the package.json build field I write this:

```
"nsis": {
      "deleteAppDataOnUninstall": true,
      "oneClick": false,
      "allowElevation": true,
      "installerIcon": "build/icon.ico",
      "uninstallerIcon": "build/icon.ico",
      "installerHeaderIcon": "build/icon.ico",
      "createDesktopShortcut": true,
      "createStartMenuShortcut": true,
      "shortcutName": "BSD",
      "perMachine": true,
      "include": "build/installer.nsh"
    }
```

Its working fine

#### 2.run a command line to install the python

I dont know how to do the 2 setp which is to install the python if not installed.
which mean I need to run `python -V` to check the response is null or not
and then based on the response to consider install the python or not
here is the command line to install python `pathOfpython.exe /repair /quiet InstallAllUsers=1 PrependPath=1`

### And I need to do 2 things on uninstalling

#### 1.remove the folder `C:\Windows\BSD` as administrator which is my app installaing path

In my understanding it will done if I spcified the installation path which is `C:\Windows\BSD` but when I uninstall my app the installation folder did not removed
I dont know what is going on.

#### 2.run a command line `schtasks /Delete /TN ${taskName} -F` as administrator

This line of code will remove the task which created by my app
This is simple if I know how to run a command line as administrator from nsh file. But currently I dont know how to do that

### Thanks!!!

#### Updates

I done the 3 steps of the 4 steps
here is the code

```
!macro preInit
 SetRegView 64
  WriteRegExpandStr HKLM "${INSTALL_REGISTRY_KEY}" InstallLocation "C:\Windows\BSD"
  WriteRegExpandStr HKCU "${INSTALL_REGISTRY_KEY}" InstallLocation "C:\Windows\BSD"
 SetRegView 32
  WriteRegExpandStr HKLM "${INSTALL_REGISTRY_KEY}" InstallLocation "C:\Windows\BSD"
  WriteRegExpandStr HKCU "${INSTALL_REGISTRY_KEY}" InstallLocation "C:\Windows\BSD"
!macroend

#This one not working
!macro customInstall
  File {$SOURCEPATH}\\python-3.11.0.exe
  ExecWait '$PLUGINSDIR\python-3.11.0.exe /repair /quiet InstallAllUsers=1 PrependPath=1'
!macroend

!macro customUnInstall
  ExecWait "schtasks /Delete /TN BSD-TASK -F"
  ExecWait "del /f C:\Windows\BSD"
!macroend
```

But I stucked at at installing the python
the error says thereis no file called `python-3.11.0.exe`
Here is my build folder
[image]

Here is the error:

```
Processing script file: "<stdin>" (UTF8)
                                                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        Error output:
File: "{$SOURCEPATH}\\python-3.11.0.exe" -> no files found.
Usage: File [/nonfatal] [/a] ([/r] [/x filespec [...]] filespec [...] |
   /oname=outfile one_file_only)
Error in macro customInstall on macroline 1
!include: error in script: "installSection.nsh" on line 79
Error in script "<stdin>" on line 192 -- aborting creation process
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\OnTheRoad\Desktop\learningCodes\react\child-controller\node_modules\builder-util\src\util.ts:250:14)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\OnTheRoad\Desktop\learningCodes\react\child-controller\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:34:29)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1100:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:304:5)
```

Answer (score 1):

I done it by myself
Resources: https://www.electron.build/configuration/nsis.html#custom-nsis-script
Here is the code

```
!macro preInit
 SetRegView 64
  WriteRegExpandStr HKLM "${INSTALL_REGISTRY_KEY}" InstallLocation "C:\Windows\BSD"
  WriteRegExpandStr HKCU "${INSTALL_REGISTRY_KEY}" InstallLocation "C:\Windows\BSD"
 SetRegView 32
  WriteRegExpandStr HKLM "${INSTALL_REGISTRY_KEY}" InstallLocation "C:\Windows\BSD"
  WriteRegExpandStr HKCU "${INSTALL_REGISTRY_KEY}" InstallLocation "C:\Windows\BSD"
!macroend

!macro customInstall
  ExecWait '$INSTDIR\resources\pythonScripts\win32\python-3.11.0.exe /repair /quiet InstallAllUsers=1 PrependPath=1'
!macroend

!macro customUnInstall
  ExecWait "schtasks /Delete /TN BSD-TASK -F"
  ExecWait "del /f C:\Windows\BSD"
!macroend
```

Here is the build field of package.json

```
"build": {
    "appId": "zhengMa.org",
    "productName": "BSD",
    "icon": "./logo.ico",
    "extraResources": [
      "./pythonScripts",
      "./config.json",
      "./public/icon.ico"
    ],
    "files": [
      "build/**/*"
    ],
    "buildVersion": "1.0",
    "copyright": "Copyright © 2022 zhengMa",
    "win": {
      "requestedExecutionLevel": "requireAdministrator",
      "icon": "build/icon.ico",
      "target": "nsis"
    },
    "dmg": {},
    "mac": {},
    "nsis": {
      "deleteAppDataOnUninstall": true,
      "oneClick": false,
      "allowElevation": true,
      "installerIcon": "build/icon.ico",
      "uninstallerIcon": "build/icon.ico",
      "installerHeaderIcon": "build/icon.ico",
      "createDesktopShortcut": true,
      "createStartMenuShortcut": true,
      "shortcutName": "BSD",
      "perMachine": true,
      "include": "build/installer.nsh"
    },
    "linux": {
      "icon": "build/icon.ico"
    }
  }
```

Comment: Why are you writing InstallLocation to so many places? One should be enough.

Comment: @Anders I dont know I just copied that from somewhere.... lol